# how to remove at once text/character from both sides of a given character/text (#regex)?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

What is the simplest way of removing text on both left and right side of a given character/text in `r`?

I have an example of the following dataset:
`a = c("C:\\final docs with data/Gakenke_New_Sanitation.xlsx", "C:\\final docs with data/Gatsibo_New_Sanitation.xlsx",  "C:\\final docs with data/Rutsiro_New_Sanitation.xlsx")`

My expected output is to remain with: **Gakenke, Gatsibo** and **Rutsiro**.

I know, I can breakdown this task and handle it using `mutate()` as the following:

`a %>% mutate(a  = str_remove(a, "C.+/"), a = str_remove(a,"_.+"))`.

My question now is which simple `pattern` can I pass to that mutate function to remain with my intended results: **Gakenke, Gatsibo** and **Rutsiro**.

Any help is much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Try `str_remove_all(a, "^.*/|_.*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
a = c("C:\\final docs with data/Gakenke_New_Sanitation.xlsx", "C:\\final docs with data/Gatsibo_New_Sanitation.xlsx",  "C:\\final docs with data/Rutsiro_New_Sanitation.xlsx")
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(a, "^.*/|_.*")
## => [1] "Gakenke" "Gatsibo" "Rutsiro"
```

The `stringr::str_remove_all` removes all occurrences of the found pattern. `^.*/|_.*` matches a string from the start till the last `/` and then from the `_` till end of the string (note the string is assumed to have no line break chars).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract` and lookaround:

```r
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  str_extract("(?<=data\\/).*(?=\\_New)")

#> [1] "Gakenke" "Gatsibo" "Rutsiro"
```